# Getting started Webcrawling

Tags: python, html

I am trying to get started with webcrawling.
My main struggle is that I need a visual interface linked to python that allows me to see what is happening as I crawl the webpage. The main idea is that I have this webpage which after I load the url I have to press an x to be redirected to a new page from which I want to extract some data. However, using an inspector I am having a hard time finding the actual redirecting link.

link:https://shop.axs.co.uk/Lw%2fYCwAAAAA6dpvSAAAAAABB%2fv%2f%2f%2fwD%2f%2f%2f%2f%2fBXRoZW8yAP%2f%2f%2f%2f%2f%2f%2f%2f%2f%2f

PS: The main reason is because I want to buy some concert tickets, to go see a band my dad loves, but tickets are currently sold out. Sometimes people resell theirs and I want to detect when tickets are available on the second page and then give myself a notification that on the visual interface I am using I am able to proceed to buy the tickets.

I know I am asking for alot but I really want to get me and my dad to the concert.

Thank you in advance kind stranger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with. You need to use Selenium because interacting with javascript requires something more advance than just a **scraper**.

There you have a simple tutorial:

https://realpython.com/modern-web-automation-with-python-and-selenium/

Comment: Ok, so the redirecting is done with additional javascripts than probably right?

Comment: The most probable. Your task is to simulate clicking the "X" element. Selenium is a tool, which allows you to do this. Next, you will receive a desired content, which you can simply scrap.

The key command will be looking something like that:

find_element_by_class('btn-close-svg pull-right').click()

Comment: Thanks for giving me the starting tools. I think I am almost there, however I am trying to simulate the click but it is telling me that the class does not exist when I run:
browser.find_element_by_class_name('btn-close-svg pull-right').click()
I do not think it is in a frame what happens to be the problem for other people, any idea how I can access it?
EDIT: working with xpath tells me the path does not exist